# How can I overwrite an existing folder created by OS Lib in python?

Tags: python, runtime-error, errno

I am trying to master the OS Lib in python by making a folder creator. Right now, it creates the folder and you can choose to rename the folder or not. The default name is 'New Folder', and I tested to see what would happen if I left it that way.

When I went to create again, because the default name is 'New Folder', it gave me `[Errno17], or 'file already exists`' error.

I am wondering how I would be able to overwrite that file allowing me to create a new folder.

Here's my code:

```
import os

os.chdir("/home/kalvyn/Desktop")

def foldermolder():
    print("Hello, welcome to Folder Molder!")
    print(" ")
    create = input("Would you like to create a folder? Y/N:")
    if create == 'Y' or 'y':
        os.mkdir('New Folder')
        namech = input('Folder created. The folder is currently named "New Folder". Woulf you like to change the name? Y/N')
        if namech == 'Y' or 'y':
            name = input("What would you like to name it?")
            os.rename('New Folder', name)
            print(" ")
            yn = input("Will that be all? Y/N:")
            if yn == 'Y' or 'y':
                quit()
            if yn == 'N' or 'n':
                foldermolder()
        if namech == 'N' or 'n':
            quit()


    if create == 'N' or 'n':
        nc = input('Would you like to exit? Y/N:')
        if nc == 'Y' or 'y':
            quit()
        if nc == 'N' or 'n':
            foldermolder()

foldermolder()
quit()
```

Comment: what is your expected behavior if the folder has some files inside?

Comment: If I create a folder, and it has the same name as an existing one, it will print 'Would you like to overwrite this file? Y/N:' and if Y or y: os.deletedirs('New Folder')

Comment: The behavior is the same with files inside as well.

Comment: you can't create folder with the same name - besides why to create folder with the same name if you already have it. Use `os.path.exists()` and `os.path.isfile()` and `os.path.isdirectiory()` to check directory name/path and don't create if already exists.

Comment: why don't you ask for folder name before you create it. If user gives empty name then use name `New File`.

Comment: Yep it worked thanks guys !!!